# How to build a List of Object that contains a list with a groupBy from a list in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking for a way to generate a list of an object called Contracts.

In Input I have a list of Contracts composed by a `ID, ContractName, Filename`.  I'm looking for a way to have as output a list of Contracts with the name and with an `IEnumerable<Documents> (ID, Filename)` of string that will collect the Ids and the FileName.

A Contract is like many files gathered by the name.

I know I can use Linq and I have to use a groupby, and I have difficulties to populate the IEnumerable.

Input List

```
ID, ContractName, FileName 
01, Contract1, File 1
02, Contract1, File 2
03, Contract1, File 3
04, Contract2, File 4
05, Contract3, File 5
06, Contract3, File 6
07, Contract3, File 7
```

Output List :

```
Contract 1, { {01, File 1},{02, File 2},{ 03, File 3} }
Contract 2, { {04, File 4}}
Contract 1, { {05, File 5},{06, File 6},{ 07, File 7} }
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you came up to and express what difficulties you had with it?

Comment: Also take a look at [ask] and how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear, but basically an IEnumerable with the matching objects will be part of each element of the `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` list that is returned from the `GroupBy()` method.

Example:

```
var contractGroups = contracts.GroupBy(c => c.ContractName);
foreach(var contractGroup in contractGroups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(contractGroup.Key + ":");
    foreach(var contractFile in contractGroup)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ID " + contractFile.ID + " = " + contractFile.Filename);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}

// ...or create more specific container objects for the result
var contractFiles = contractGroups.Select(cg => new { ContractName = cg.Key, Files = cg.Select(file => new { file.ID, file.Filename }) });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ToLookup` to create a [`Lookup<k, v>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var contractNameLookup = contracts.ToLookup(c => c.ContractName);
```

now you can lookup all files that belong to a name easily and efficiently:

```
List<string> fileNamesOfContract = contractNameLookup["foo"]
  .Select(c => c.Filename)
  .ToList();
```

If the name is not in the lookup you will have an empty list.

> A `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` resembles a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. The
>   difference is that a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` maps keys to single
>   values, whereas a `Lookup<TKey, TElement`> **maps keys to collections of
>   values**.